# How to detect a heat emitting object in a distance from 10 - 50cm?

Tags: infrared, heat

If I have a heat emitting object like a heater, radiator or hot cup of coffee, what sensor can I use to detect it by the fact that it is emitting heat?

I have hc-sr04 sensors but they use ultrasound and so are not suited to this. I have found this [infrared sensor](https://www.amazon.co.uk/DAOKAI%C2%AE-Infrared-Obstacle-Avoidance-Arduino/dp/B00X6LBN92/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1479333136&sr=8-1&keywords=infrared%20sensor) but I am not sure if it detects heat or just distance.

To put context as to what I am asking for, lets say I'm using the hcsr04 as the front eyes of a robot and need something to detect heat from 10cm to 50cm in front of the bot too.

Does anyone know what I can use or is the infrared sensors I provided above suitable along with any other type of infrared sensor?

Comment: The sensor you found uses IR to measure distance, it will be no good to detect warm/hot objects. A standard PIR (passive infra red detector) is a motion sensor that detects the movement of warm objects, but cannot detect stationary objects. The [Omron D6T MEMS Thermal IR Sensor](https://www.omron.com/ecb/products/sensor/11/d6t.html)  is claimed to detect the IR from stationary objects, but you will have to check the specs to see if it can detect something the size of a cup of coffee.

Comment: Pair a infrared thermometer with a ultrasonic distance sensor?

Comment: Are you trying to detect an actual temperature, or just that something is above a certain level?

Comment: take a look at this question: **[Claculating Optical Lens for Temprature IR Sensor. (heat emitting 20x20cm object in a distance from 13cm)]** (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/500631/calculating-optical-lens-for-temperature-ir-sensor-heat-emitting-20x20cm-objec)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that whatever you use for measureing heat, the reading will likely diminish with distance. Thus you should not try to use a heat sensor alone to measure distance (unless the object is of an already-known constant temperature).

They make pyroelectric sensors ("non-contact infrared thermometers") for absolute readings. However, I've found that they typically have a wide viewing angle, which can cause trouble when you wish to pin-point heat.
[image: MLX90614 sensor]

The [MLX90614](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9570) is an example that I think measures with a 45 degree cone. So as the measuring distance increases, the measurement "area" increases. Thus a small, hot object can be "washed-out" by nearby cooler objects. Thus you may need to put "blinders" around it for a more precise measurement, though the blinders will still lower the average reading.
See below for a very technical diagram:
[image: Pyroelectric sensor in a tube]

As Jack Creasey mentioned, pyroelectric sensors (the kind used in motion-detecting PIR (passive Infrared) modules) will detect IR heat. However, the ones Jack posted are for heat *differentials*, (movement of heat). Each unit actually contains *two* IR heat sensors inside, right next to eachother, and the unit measures the difference between them. So when there is heat movement, their output changes. However, they are *very affordable* ($1-3).

What's a maker to do?

A cheap hack would be to cover one side of a PIR sensor unit's window, so that only one internal sensor can see. This gives a more "absolute" value to the readings.

[image: PIR sensor half covered with foil]

[**See this blog link on getting absolute values from a PIR sensor.**](https://sites.google.com/a/gr0b.com/0_o/updates/pyroelectricinfraredsensorspirthermograph)

Note that I have personally tried the methods described in that link above for the purposes of measuring body heat. I was not very successful at detecting a person from more than a meter away, and I also noticed that if I held a hot object in front of the sensor, the output would slowly decay back to the baseline over a course of ~30 seconds. Thus pulling the heat source away caused the sensor to report a negative reading until it normalized again. 
Results will of course depend on the temperature of the object being measured, the object's [emissivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emissivity), and the sensor model (I tried using the [PIR_D202X](http://www.futurlec.com/PIR_Sensors.shtml) and the PIS209S.) Oh, and I didn't use a fresnel lens, that could make a difference too.
Below is the output of my foiled-PIR sensor test when I waved my hand in front of it (maybe 10 inches above):
[image: PIR module output]
That data was aquired with no futher hardware or software changes to the signal. There were about 22 levels of quantized output. Notice how the output drops below the baseline immedietly after the heat is removed.

To further increase the sensitivity, a reflective dish (perhaps parabolic) would increase the amount of radiation on the sensor. Some IR is lost upon reflection, but smooth metal, even aluminum foil, will reflect a good amount.
See below for another state-of-the-art diagram:
[image: IR sensor with parabolic dish]

If you don't need actual temperature readings, and instead just need to detect something above a set temperature, you could try an [IR flame detector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flame_detector). These are typically sensitive to IR emitted by CO2 (IR wavelength of 4.4μm). Here is a [cheap IR flame sensor](http://www.sainsmart.com/ir-infrared-flame-detection-sensor-module-detect-fire-flame-sensor-for-arduino.html). While it's labeled with a range of 760nm~1100nm (0.76μm~1.1μm), the sensitivity is adjustable, and you may be able to tune it to trigger around a certain set temperature. It has both digital and analog output. You would probably need to use the analog output to trigger a digital comparison.
[image: IR flame sensor]

IR heat varies in wavelength. I can say that many IR thermal cameras tend to be tuned in the range of 7μm~13μm. This range covers the typical heat emitted from animals and common objects. The [MLX90614](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9570) sensor from further above is senitive in the 5.5μm~14μm range.

Answer (score 0):

The DAOKAI IR sensors work on reflected IR not on target 'heat'.

What you seem to be looking for is a Pyroelectric sensor such as this [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00FDPO9B8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FDPO9B8) or this [https://www.amazon.com/TOOGOO-Pyroelectric-Infrared-Motion-Detector/dp/B00SO1TG2K](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00SO1TG2K)

The sensor used in these products is most likely this type: http://www.glolab.com/pirparts/pirmanual.PDF

These do NOT sense distance but will sense movement of a 'hot' object as it crosses the lens.
For the application you want you could use a movement detector such as those above by creating a thinner window and then scanning back and forth across the space in front of you (mount it on an RC servo).

PS. I use these exact movement detectors to sense my cats, though I use the Fresnel lenses provided.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this is to use two standard temperature sensors. One is placed within the focal point of a small reflective dish, the other is an ambient temperature sensor which gives you the correct bias value.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to know if some HOT object suddenly appeared in front of the robot?

Use a plain silicon diode, soldered to 1cm^2 bit of copper foil.
That foil will gather lots of energy, and the diode will be part of the heat-flow path, thus 2,000 microvolts per degreeC will be the response.

You must bias the diode, with some low current; 1uA or 10uA is fine.